# how to remove class on other element with toggleClass closest

Tags: jquery, addclass, toggleclass, closest

Hi I've got this jQuery:

```
var $burger = $('#burger'),
$body = $('body'),
$main = $('main'),
$menu = $('menu'),
$menuItem = $('.nav__item--parent'),
$trigger = $('.nav__item--parent > a'),
$subMenu = $('.nav__sub-menu');

$burger.click(function() {
  return $body.toggleClass('active');
  return false
});
$('.nav__item--parent > a').click(function() {
  $('.nav__item--parent.open').removeClass('open');
  $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('open');
  $main.toggleClass('push-down');
});
```

I need .push-down to be removed if they click the same li again.

/// Update ///

I've now made use of an answer below (thanks) to get to this

```
$('.nav__item--parent > a').click(function() {
  var $li = $(this).closest('li');
  $main.toggleClass('push-down', $li.hasClass('open'));
  $('.nav__item--parent.open').removeClass('open');
  $li.toggleClass('open');
  $main.toggleClass('push-down');
});
```

The issue is now if they click a li which toggle the push-down correctly I need to remove .open ? :-/

Comment: Without the HTML I guessed at the correct true/false. You may need to reverse the logic of my example with `!$li.hasClass('open')`. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `"open"` state of the closest `li` with `hasClass()` before you do the toggling. If you pass a `boolean` second parameter to `toggleClass`, it sets or clears the class based on `true` or `false` values.

e.g.

```
$('.nav__item--parent > a').click(function() {
   var $li = $(this).closest('li');
   $main.toggleClass('push-down', $li.hasClass('open'));
   $('.nav__item--parent.open').removeClass('open');
   $li.toggleClass('open');
});
```

Note: toggleClass is not technically correct in the last part (as it is cleared by the line before, so only sets it). You want to exclude the clicked `LI` from the removeClass with `.not()`:

e.g.

```
$('.nav__item--parent > a').click(function() {
   var $li = $(this).closest('li');
   $main.toggleClass('push-down', $li.hasClass('open'));
   $('.nav__item--parent.open').not($li).removeClass('open');
   $li.toggleClass('open');
});
```